# Microsoft Access SQL Homework Issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

For each maker that produces printers, find the number of printer models produced by this maker. Output a table consisting of two columns: (maker, number of models). Sort the result by numbers of models in ascending order.

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT maker, Count(*) AS [Number of Models]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT model
     FROM Product
     WHERE type='printer')
```

It doesn't work, prompts and asks me to enter a maker instead of inserting makers from my list.

Comment: When MS Access prompts you to enter something, it means it doesn't recognise it so it thinks it is a parameter. In other words, it doesn't recognise word 'maker'. In the query as written, clearly there is no 'maker' because your subselect only returns a column called model.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this query :

```
SELECT maker, Count(distinct model) AS [Number of Models] 
FROM Product WHERE type='printer'
group by maker
order by Count(distinct model)
```